# - Webpack error after angular 5.1 upgrade, but no webpack in package.json

Tags: angular, webpack

Webpack error after angular 5.1 upgrade, but no webpack in package.json

Here is my Package.json

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "0.0.40",
    "@angular/animations": "^5.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "^5.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.1.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^5.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.1.0",
    "@angular/service-worker": "^5.1.0",
    "bootstrap": "3.3.7",
    "breeze-bridge-angular": "4.0.1",
    "breeze-client": "1.6.3",
    "core-js": "2.4.1",
    "font-awesome": "4.7.0",
    "jquery": "3.1.1",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^2.0.0-beta.9",
    "ngx-color-picker": "4.5.0",
    "ngx-gallery": "2.3.0",
    "primeng": "4.3.0",
    "quill": "1.3.2",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.2",
    "screenfull": "3.0.2",
    "toastr": "2.1.2",
    "ts-helpers": "1.1.1",
    "zone.js": "0.8.14"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.6.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.1.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.53",
    "@types/node": "8.0.7",
    "codelyzer": "2.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "3.2.0",
    "karma": "1.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "0.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "0.2.2",
    "protractor": "5.1.0",
    "ts-node": "2.0.0",
    "tslint": "4.4.2",
    "typescript": "2.5.3"
}
```

All installs great with no errors of any kind...

My error after running ng serve

---

```
@angular/compiler-cli@5.1.0 requires typescript@'>=2.4.2 <2.5.0' but 2.5.3 
was found instead.
Using this version can result in undefined behaviour and difficult to debug 
problems.

Please run the following command to install a compatible version of 
TypeScript.

npm install typescript@'>=2.4.2 <2.5.0'

To disable this warning run "ng set warnings.typescriptMismatch=false".

** NG Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your 
browser on http://localhost:4200/ **
Date: 2017-12-07T12:54:30.173Z
Hash: f4590b1acb9318fb9940
Time: 7003ms
chunk {inline} inline.bundle.js (inline) 5.79 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {main} main.bundle.js (main) 2.93 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {styles} styles.bundle.js (styles) 1.21 MB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {vendor} vendor.bundle.js (vendor) 854 kB [initial] [rendered]

ERROR in Error: No NgModule metadata found for 'AppModule'.
at NgModuleResolver.resolve (C:\Users\Mike\...\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:20249:23)
at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (C:\Users\Mike\...\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:15218:60)
at visitLazyRoute (C:\Users\Mike\...\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:31063:104)
at AotCompiler.listLazyRoutes (C:\Users\Mike\Source\...\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:31031:20)
at AngularCompilerProgram.listLazyRoutes (C:\Users\Mike\Source\Repos\...\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\transformers\program.js:156:30)
at Function.NgTools_InternalApi_NG_2.listLazyRoutes (C:\Users\Mike\Source\Repos\...\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtools_api.js:44:36)
at AngularCompilerPlugin._getLazyRoutesFromNgtools (C:\Users\Mike\Source\Repos\...\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\angular_compiler_plugin.js:247:66)
at Promise.resolve.then.then (C:\Users\Mike\Source\Repos\...\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\angular_compiler_plugin.js:561:50)
at <anonymous>
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)

webpack: Failed to compile.
Terminate batch job (Y/N)? y
```

---

Not to sure why webpack is the cause as I dont have it. I did have it before but since ran

npm remove webpack
rimraf node_modules

Comment: The angular cli use Webpack under the hood .. so it is why it gives toyou error ..the error is not related to webpack or packages but it is about your code in the AppModule ts file

Comment: OK, Ive checked the App.Module.ts file and cant see anything wrong with it. It is the same as before and which worked on v5.0.3. 

Do I need to install webpack. I would rather NOT if I dont need too...

Comment: I have removed some entryComponents, This has allowed the build to go through.

********
      // entryComponents: [
    //     NavMenuThemedComponent,
    //     NavMenu01Component,
    //     NavMenu02Component
    // ],

Comment: Angular doesn't support the version of Typescript you've installed. Try running this: npm install typescript@2.4.2 --save-exact

Comment: Webpack is already installed by the cli .. so give  a try doing this: npm install --save webpack ... try to remove node_modules folder .. delete also the package-lock.json and do a npm install .... and ng serve ..